# Recreate textPath with pure JS

Tags: node.js

I need to create text on an arc without transform attributes so `<textPath>` is unfortunately not the answer, but I would like to know how it works.

The approach I've taken is to parse text into glyphs with opentype.js. Then somehow use the glyphPath commands to place the characters one by one onto the path. I figured [forEachGlyph](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/blob/423b611adade6bf84ac3be58362f3d670a41bcb1/src/font.js#L296) would be a good place to expose the glyphs.

```
const textPath = (props: {
    text: string;
    path: string;
    font: Buffer;
    fontSize: number;
}): string => {
    let f = opentype.parse(props.font.buffer);

    let fullPathOnPath = new Path();

    f.forEachGlyph(
        props.text,
        0,
        0,
        props.fontSize,
        {},
        (glyph, gX, gY, gFontSize) => {
            let glyphPath = glyph.getPath(gX, gY, gFontSize, {}, this);

            // transform glyphPath to be on path

            fullPathOnPath.extend(glyphPath);
        }
    );

    return fullPathOnPath.toPathData(3);
};
```

Here's some resources
[textPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textpath)
[svgpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgpath)

Comment: In node.js you could try [svg-text-to-path](https://github.com/paulzi/svg-text-to-path) - not sure if it also supports `<textpath>` conversions. In a **browser** you could actually calculate all characters positions and rotations via `getStartPositionOfChar()`and `getRotationOfChar()`  – and flatten these transformations to hardcoded pathData (see [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/KKxbeVG)). But I'm afraid these methods are not available in node.js